# Should NHibernate clear distributed 2nd Level Cache on ISessionFactory.Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm working on [a `CacheProvider` for Redis](https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/NHibernate.Caches.Redis). I've stumbled upon something quite curious about the pre-built [NHibernate Cache Providers](http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Caches/).

When in a distributed environment, I'd expect each web server to share the same NHibernate cache. Therefore, if one of the web servers is removed, it would also be expected that the cache isn't affected (because *another* web server in the cluster would still be using that cache!).

However, according to my tests and the source of these providers, each time an `ISessionFactory` is closed (calling `Dispose` or `Close`), **the whole cache region is cleared**!

For example, [the Memcached Provider](http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Caches/MemCache/NHibernate.Caches.MemCache/MemCacheClient.cs?revision=1697&view=markup#l224) calls `Clear()` when `Destroy()` is called. In [the `Close()` of `ISessionFactory`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/88a4f98deb4e4c908d193d12660d741b34d4c8ea/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionFactoryImpl.cs#L788), each created `ICache` has `Destroy()` called and then finally the `ICacheProvider` has `Stop()` called. Therefore, even though Memcached is meant to be a distributed cache, it gets cleared when the `ISessionFactory` is disposed of!

Is this *really* the expected behavior in a distributed environment? Clearing the *distributed* cache each time a web server is taken down seems like it would generate a *lot* of cache misses and therefore losing the whole point of caching!

What I'm thinking is that `Destroy()` should be used to clean up any *resources* (like a `Dispose()` ... but it was brought over from Hibernate) and these cache providers have a **serious bug**. For example, a [*Hibernate* Memcached cache provdier I found](https://github.com/raykrueger/hibernate-memcached/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/hibernate/memcached/MemcachedCache.java#L186) *does not* `clear()` on `destroy()`.

FWIW, I've [posted this](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nhibernate-development/oqGFx7BOYew/discussion) on the NHibernate Development Group.

Comment: This is interesting. I suggest you bring it up in the [NHibernate Development group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/nhibernate-development)

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon - Thanks for this, I've submitted a post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. A distributed cache should NOT behave like this because it defeats the purpose. When `Destroy()` is called, the function called in the provider should be `Dispose()`. This function merely disconnects the cache and not clears it so the data for other clients remains intact in the distributed cache.

Comment: Exactly what I have been thinking. Anyone using the existing cache providers for NHibernate are *most likely* getting way more cache misses than they should!